# corda- QUASAR WARNING: Quasar Java Agent isn't running trigger error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing the '-javaagent' JVM argument

Tags: intellij-idea, corda, quasar

I have installed the Corda version 4.
I am currently not able to run debug. If I let the default, I have an error from Intellij on "Shortencommend line".

I mofidied the configuration as bellow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppZcN.png)

When I run in debug mode, I get the errors below:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:57000,suspend=y,server=n -ea -javaagent:../lib/quasar.jar -Dco.paralleluniverse.fibers.verifyInstrumentation -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Users\YYYYY\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\YYYYY\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\YYYYY\AppData\Local\Temp\1\idea_classpath1610987467 com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.XXXXXX.flow.XXXXXXFlowTests
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57000', transport: 'socket'
[quasar] WARNING: Can't determine super class of com/intellij/rt/debugger/agent/CaptureStorage$CapturedStack
2019-03-07 10:09:25,976 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
QUASAR WARNING: Assertions enabled. This may harm performance.
QUASAR WARNING: Quasar Java Agent isn't running. If you're using another instrumentation method you can ignore this message; otherwise, please refer to the Getting Started section in the Quasar documentation.
QUASAR WARNING: Fibers are set to verify instrumentation. This may *severely* harm performance.
[INFO ] 10:09:40.848 [main] TestCordappImpl.apply - Generating CorDapp jar from local project in C:\ZZZZZZ\RRRRRR\EEEEEE\Demo\src\XXXXXXPrototype\contracts ...
> Task :contracts:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :contracts:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :contracts:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :contracts:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :contracts:configureCordappFatJar
> Task :contracts:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :contracts:jar UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
[INFO ] 10:09:45.643 [main] TestCordappImpl.apply - Generating CorDapp jar from local project in C:\ZZZZZZ\RRRRRR\EEEEEE\Demo\src\XXXXXXPrototype\workflows ...
> Task :contracts:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :contracts:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :contracts:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :contracts:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :contracts:configureCordappFatJar
> Task :contracts:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :contracts:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :workflows:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :workflows:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :workflows:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :workflows:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :workflows:configureCordappFatJar
> Task :workflows:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :workflows:jar UP-TO-DATE....
....doing nothing
[INFO ] 10:10:03.705 [main] ClassloaderUtils.logElapsedTime - Contracts loading for 'C:\Users\YYYYY\AppData\Local\Temp\1\attachment6754596995920191526.jar' took 34 msec
[INFO ] 10:10:03.748 [main] NodeAttachmentService.invoke - Stored new attachment: id=CECC460ED2D5F196CED8988EDDBDFB039FDC145507650BEE2E6CD92862638780 uploader=app filename=null
[INFO ] 10:10:03.754 [main] NotaryLoader.loadService - Starting notary service: class net.corda.node.services.transactions.SimpleNotaryService
[INFO ] 10:10:03.759 [main] SinglePartyNotaryService.<init> - Starting notary in validating mode

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing the '-javaagent' JVM argument. Make sure you run the tests with the Quasar java agent attached to your JVM.
See https://docs.corda.net/troubleshooting.html - 'Fiber classes not instrumented' for more details.

    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.checkQuasarJavaAgentPresence(SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.kt:312)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.start(SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.kt:140)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$7.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:392)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$7.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:120)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:236)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:221)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:199)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:205)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:371)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.start(InternalMockNetwork.kt:346)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNodeImpl(InternalMockNetwork.kt:471)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:449)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:444)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNotaries$node_driver(InternalMockNetwork.kt:253)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:236)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:149)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:299)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:288)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:297)
    at com.XXXXXX.flow.XXXXXXFlowTests.setup(XXXXXXFlowTests.kt:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)


kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property network has not been initialized

    at com.XXXXXX.flow.XXXXXXFlowTests.tearDown(XXXXXXFlowTests.kt:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57000', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: `-javaagent:../lib/quasar.jar` could be an issue, try using the absolute path instead.

Comment: I did it, but Intellij (or java) is not able to load the quasar library! I put a wrong path to check, I have an error message saying the jar is not found. What I am sure about is that quasar.jar is loaded.

Comment: I can't see the rest of your command line. The bit before `../lib/quasar` is cut off. Can you update your question with the full command line?

Comment: limited by Stack overflow: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:59495,suspend=y,server=n -ea -javaagent:../lib/quasar.jar -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Users\fbenanta\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar

Comment: and : -javaagent:C:\Users\fbenanta\.IdeaIC2018.3\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\fbenanta\AppData\Local\Temp\1\idea_classpath611726309 com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.bluecatalyst.flow.BluecatalystFlowTests

Answer (score 0):

From Corda test documentation:

We recommend editing your IntelliJ preferences so that you use the Gradle runner - this means that **the quasar utils plugin** will make sure that some flags (like -javaagent - see below) **are set for you**.

To switch to using the Gradle runner:

- Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Runner (or search for runner)

  - Windows: this is in “Settings”
  - MacOS: this is in “Preferences”
- Set “Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle” to true
- Set “Run test using:” to “Gradle Test Runner”

changing this config fixed the issue for me.